# Allow traffic from all sources with Kubernetes Network Policies

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-networkpolicy

Whats the difference between the following two network policies? They only differ by `spec.ingress.from.podSelector`.

First network policy:

```
controlplane ~ ➜  cat netpol1.yaml 
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: ingress-to-nptest-1
  namespace: default
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      run: np-test-1
  policyTypes:
    - Ingress
  ingress:
    - ports:
        - protocol: TCP
          port: 80
```

Second network policy:

```
controlplane ~ ➜  cat netpol2.yaml 
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: ingress-to-nptest-2
  namespace: default
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      run: np-test-1
  policyTypes:
    - Ingress
  ingress:
    - from:
      - podSelector: {}
      ports:
        - protocol: TCP
          port: 80
```

When I run `kubectl describe netpol` it suggests a different behaviour, but I can't figure out what the difference is.

In the first case it allows traffic "From:  (traffic not restricted by source)":

```
controlplane ~ ➜  k describe netpol ingress-to-nptest-1
Name:         ingress-to-nptest-1
Namespace:    default
Created on:   2023-03-16 07:53:04 -0400 EDT
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
Spec:
  PodSelector:     run=np-test-1
  Allowing ingress traffic:
    To Port: 80/TCP
    From: <any> (traffic not restricted by source)
  Not affecting egress traffic
  Policy Types: Ingress
```

In the second case it allows traffic from pods that match "PodSelector:none":

```
controlplane ~ ➜  k describe netpol ingress-to-nptest-2
Name:         ingress-to-nptest-2
Namespace:    default
Created on:   2023-03-16 07:54:09 -0400 EDT
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
Spec:
  PodSelector:     run=np-test-1
  Allowing ingress traffic:
    To Port: 80/TCP
    From:
      PodSelector: <none>
  Not affecting egress traffic
  Policy Types: Ingress
```

The [Kubernetes API reference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.21/#networkpolicyingressrule-v1-networking-k8s-io) suggests that this is equivalent to the first network policy:

> podSelector: This is a label selector which selects Pods. This field follows standard label selector semantics; if present but empty, it selects all pods.

Is it correct that in both cases traffic from every source is allowed? Are both network policies equivalent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research I think I found the answer myself. The [Kubernetes API reference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.20/#networkpolicyingressrule-v1-networking-k8s-io) states that:

> spec.ingress.from: If this field is empty or missing, this rule matches all sources (traffic not restricted by source).

It also states the following on [another page](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.20/#networkpolicypeer-v1-networking-k8s-io):

> spec.ingress.from.podSelector: if present but empty, it selects all pods.

> spec.ingress.from.namespaceSelector: if present but empty, it selects all namespaces.

As we can also specify `spec.ingress.from.namespaceSelector`, it follows that it would be possible to set `spec.ingress.from.podSelector` to `{}`, but `spec.ingress.from.namespaceSelector` to some namespace. This would select all pods from some namespace. If, on the other hand, we would leave `spec.ingress.from` empty, we would select all pods from all namespaces.

It follows that both network policies are the same, but only as long as `spec.ingress.from.namespaceSelector` is empty as well.

Answer (score 0):

If I am right, the only difference I could see is this section:

```yaml
    - from:
      - podSelector: {}
```

that does not exclude anything. So technically they are the same.

Comment: Your answer is just an assertion. Could be right or wrong, who knows? Only an explanation or proof of your statement would make your answer valuable.

Comment: You added a condition that it is empty and matches all pods. So presence or absence of these two lines does not matter.